# Platform.RunLater(), swingUtilities.InvokeLater(), and Thread(runnable) confusion

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, javafx

please can someone help me clarify these concepts am from c++ and trying to learn java for some time now and just got onto these terms(the first two) when i attempted to try my hands on some swing application...

Comment: Please ask a more specific and answerable question or questions. Otherwise you appear to be asking someone to write several tutorials for you. What specifically confuses you?

Comment: Also, the 3 code statements that you've presented are completely different and have no overlap, other than that they all have an association with threading.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels well i was reading through a swing sample source code i wanted to use in my app and came across the first two concepts i wanted to know why not thread?? how different are they and can i interchange them and have no risk of crashing my app

Comment: Please show your code of interest, and which two code statements did you run into? You list 3 above. You ask how different are they -- again they all are pretty much orthogonal concepts from each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)`

  - From the [SwingUtilities API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html):

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed. This method should be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI. In the following example the invokeLater call queues the Runnable object doHelloWorld on the event dispatching thread and then prints a message.
>
> This queues a Runnable object on the Swing event thread so that the code that the Runnable contains, presumably code that mutates the state of a Swing GUI or that queries the state of the GUI, is run on the Swing event thread. The code that makes this call does not wait around for the Runnable to run, so there is no guarantee of order of code completion of the calling code vs. the Runnable's code.

`new Thread(Runnable r)`

- From the [Thread API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as Thread (null, target, gname), where gname is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer.

This is a constructor call that creates a Thread object with a Runnable that when started by calling `start()` on the Thread object runs the Runnable in a new thread that is background to the calling code's thread.

`Platform.runLater(Runnable r)`

- From the [Platform API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html):

  > Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future. This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller. The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted. A runnable passed into the runLater method will be executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to runLater.
- So it shows that this is just like Swing's `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)`, but is the JavaFX flavor of this.

Comment: That's about all I can tell you regarding 2 of your code statements. The 3rd you'll have to look up, or wait for a different answer from someone who is familiar with JavaFx (not me because I'm not), and if this doesn't clear anything up for you, well it's the best I can do so far given the limitations of your question since you provide no details as to the source of your confusion.